# Dynamically extend Virtus instance attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, virtus

Let's say we have a Virtus model `User`

```
class User
  include Virtus.model
  attribute :name, String, default: 'John', lazy: true
end
```

Then we create an instance of this model and extend from `Virtus.model` to add another attribute on the fly:

```
user = User.new
user.extend(Virtus.model)
user.attribute(:active, Virtus::Attribute::Boolean, default: true, lazy: true)
```

Current output:

```
user.active? # => true
user.name # => 'John'
```

But when I try to get either `attributes` or convert the object to JSON via `as_json`(or `to_json`) or `Hash` via `to_h` I get only post-extended attribute `active`:

```
user.to_h # => { active: true }
```

What is causing the problem and how can I get to convert the object without  loosing the data?

### P.S.

I have found a [github issue](https://github.com/solnic/virtus/issues/122), but it seems that it was not fixed after all (the approach recommended there doesn't work stably as well).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Building on Adrian's finding, here is a way to modify Virtus to allow what you want. All specs pass with this modification.

Essentially, Virtus already has the concept of a parent `AttributeSet`, but it's only when including `Virtus.model` in a [class](https://github.com/solnic/virtus/blob/60e7ed2dd351a84a5d4c1ba3326edef764dad25f/lib/virtus/attribute_set.rb#L9-L10).
We can extend it to consider instances as well, and even allow multiple `extend(Virtus.model)` in the same object (although that sounds sub-optimal):

```ruby
require 'virtus'
module Virtus
  class AttributeSet
    def self.create(descendant)
      if descendant.respond_to?(:superclass) && descendant.superclass.respond_to?(:attribute_set)
        parent = descendant.superclass.public_send(:attribute_set)
      elsif !descendant.is_a?(Module)
        if descendant.respond_to?(:attribute_set, true) && descendant.send(:attribute_set)
          parent = descendant.send(:attribute_set)
        elsif descendant.class.respond_to?(:attribute_set)
          parent = descendant.class.attribute_set
        end
      end
      descendant.instance_variable_set('@attribute_set', AttributeSet.new(parent))
    end
  end
end

class User
  include Virtus.model
  attribute :name, String, default: 'John', lazy: true
end

user = User.new
user.extend(Virtus.model)
user.attribute(:active, Virtus::Attribute::Boolean, default: true, lazy: true)

p user.to_h # => {:name=>"John", :active=>true}

user.extend(Virtus.model) # useless, but to show it works too
user.attribute(:foo, Virtus::Attribute::Boolean, default: false, lazy: true)

p user.to_h # => {:name=>"John", :active=>true, :foo=>false}
```

Maybe this is worth making a PR to Virtus, what do you think?

Comment: Thank you! And yes, I think PR is a great idea, it seems that quite a lot of people have struggled with this issue.

Comment: @potashin It's nice that @eregon has come up with a PR. Good job, eregon! But, did I not answer your question which is this: `What is causing the problem and how can I get to convert the object without loosing the data?`?

Comment: @Adrian I think you answered very nicely the "what is the problem", but the fix sounds rather hacky (it only addresses `to_h`, other parts of Virtus will not work), that's why I decided to try finding a cleaner solution.

Comment: @eregon My answer can fix his problem (explicitly written in the question) right away. I thought this is how SO works. *How could anyone know that he wanted a PR* to the library related to that problem that will also fix other unrelated problems (if any) that are not even mentioned in the question. But anyway, congratz @eregon!

Answer (score 3):

I haven't investigated it further, but it seems that every time you include or extend Virtus.model, it initializes a new AttributeSet and set it to @attribute_set instance variable of your User class ([source](https://github.com/solnic/virtus/blob/master/lib/virtus/attribute_set.rb#L12)). What the `to_h` or `attributes` do is they call the `get` method of the new attribute_set instance ([source](https://github.com/solnic/virtus/blob/master/lib/virtus/instance_methods.rb#L41)). Therefore, you can only get attributes after the last inclusion or the extension of `Virtus.model`.

```
class User
  include Virtus.model
  attribute :name, String, default: 'John', lazy: true
end

user = User.new
user.instance_variables
#=> []
user.send(:attribute_set).object_id
#=> 70268060523540

user.extend(Virtus.model)
user.attribute(:active, Virtus::Attribute::Boolean, default: true, lazy: true)

user.instance_variables
#=> [:@attribute_set, :@active, :@name]
user.send(:attribute_set).object_id
#=> 70268061308160
```

As you can see, the `object_id` of `attribute_set` instance before and after the extension is different which means that the former and the latter attribute_set are two different objects.

A hack I can suggest for now is this:

```
(user.instance_variables - [:@attribute_set]).each_with_object({}) do |sym, hash|
  hash[sym.to_s[1..-1].to_sym] = user.instance_variable_get(sym)
end
```